# Remove space in reference in "et al. ,"

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, natbib, sharelatex

I'm using Sharelatex to work on my thesis, and I want to use the `natbib` package and `authordate3` style for my bibliography. For some reason, when referencing a bibliography entry with multiple authors, I get a space between "et al." and the year.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{authordate3} 

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{jon99,
    author          = "Tom Jones and
                        Jack Smith and
                        John Doe",
    title           = "Wonderful Book",
    year            = "1999"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citep{jon99}

\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\end{document}
```

In Sharelatex, this gives:

[image: ugly space]

Now, I've looked around, but the only solution that seems to work is by manipulating the `authordate3.bst` file (as suggested [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general/72353)), which I obviously don't have access to, since I don't have LaTeX installed on my machine.

I've also tried changing the punctuation separation between the author and the year to include `\unskip` using `\setcitestyle{aysep={\unskip,}}`, but that unfortunately didn't work. Simply adding a negative space (such as using `\setcitestyle{aysep={\kern-ex1,}}`) fixes the space for multiple references but places the comma on top of the author's name for single references.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice MWE!

Comment: Note that `authordate3.bst` is *not* a good style for `natbib`.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. I don't have that space. As a side note note that it should be `\bibliography{biblio}` and not `\bibliography{biblio.bib}`

Comment: @karlkoeller For me, the space is there. I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @yo' Different version of packages?

Comment: @karlkoeller are you compiling through Sharelatex or your local machine? I suspect that Sharelatex's package version may indeed be different than most versions. Thanks for the side note, I got a warning while compiling but I didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: @egreg what style would you suggest? I wanted one with the last names in small caps, and authordate3 was the best choice I found.

Comment: @Martim My machine. See this discussion in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20141882#20141882

Comment: @Martim Can you use your own files in ShareLaTeX? If yes, download `authordate3.bst` from here http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/authordate

Comment: @karlkoeller I just uploaded that version of `authordate3` and it fixed the issue. Seems a little hacky, but at least it gets the job done. While we're at it, what do I need to change so that the last names of authors appear in small caps but the first names don't? I assume I need to change the `format.authors` function, right?

I'll report the version inconsistencies to Sharelatex and hopefully they'll update to the version on ctan.

Comment: This should be reported as a bug to Nelson Beebe, the upstream authordate package appears to have been fixed but that has not propagated to the version in his collection which is used in texlive.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat of a home cooked solution, but I opened the `authordate3.bst` file in my text editor and replaced the three occurrence of `{\em et~al.\ }` with `{\em et~al.}`. My `authordate3.bst` was located here `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/beebe/authordate3.bst`.

After I did that I ran your code again and all was good (I might have created some horrible problem I am not aware of?).

Below example was produced with the code Martim provided above.

[image: same code as above!]